# Could not connect MongoDB Atlas to my goorm IDE

Tags: node.js, mongoose, connection

I am a beginner here.

I am currently setting up my goorm IDE and trying to connect MongoDB Atlas.

However, I couldn't connect my MongoDB Atlas cluster to my goorm IDE which shows the below message:

ERROR failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-00-1kwgi.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed.]

I have tried to whitelist the IP with 0.0.0.0/0 as followed the tutorial of Ian Schoonover. However, I still could not connect my MongoDB Atlas.

Below is my code in IDE

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://dylanOh:123456@cluster0-1kwgi.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',{
    useNewUrlParser : true,
    useCreateIndex : true
}).then(()=>{
    console.log('Connected to DB!');
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log('ERROR',err.message);
});


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');



//Below is my testing info before setting up the database

const campgrounds =[
{name: 'Shenandoah', image:'https://www.nps.gov/shen/planyourvisit/images/20170712_A7A9022_nl_Campsites_BMCG_960.jpg?maxwidth=1200&maxheight=1200&autorotate=false'},
{name: 'Mount Rainier', image:'https://www.nps.gov/mora/planyourvisit/images/OhanaCampground2016_CMeleedy_01_web.jpeg?maxwidth=1200&maxheight=1200&autorotate=false'},
{name: 'Florida', image:'https://www.visitflorida.com/content/visitflorida/en-us/places-to-stay/campgrounds-florida/_jcr_content/full_width/vf_image.img.1280.500.jpg'}]


app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.render('landing');
});



app.get('/campgrounds', (req,res)=>{

    res.render('campgrounds', {campgrounds:campgrounds});
});

app.post('/campgrounds', (req,res)=>{
    const name=req.body.name ;
    const image=req.body.image;
    const newCampground = {name:name, image:image}
    campgrounds.push(newCampground);
    res.redirect('/campgrounds');
});


app.get('/campgrounds/new', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('new');
});



app.listen('3000', ()=>{
    console.log('YelpCamp has started!');
});
```

As an expected outcome, it should be showing 'Connected to DB!' at my terminal.

However, 'ERROR failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-00-1kwgi.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoError: bad auth Authentication failed.]' was shown.

Comment: Is **dylanOh** is your db user and **123456** is your db user's password, not your Mongo Atlas account's password?

Comment: Oh yes they are not, my Mongo Atlas account for login is different, and the 123456 I just randomly typed.

Comment: If you are using database credentials, then either your db username or password is wrong, can you check your database credentials again or create a new db user

Comment: Hi @onuriltan, I have created a second user and the DB successfully connected! Thank you for your advice and i think my first user was not working because i did not update the password on my mongoDB Atlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create a new db user since the error is an authentication error, you might forget your first created db user's password, I sometimes forget it when I first create the user :)

Comment: Yes, I did not even set the password for my first user :) just added it and everything is working out now!

Comment: Glad id worked, then can you accept as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks again for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You see “test?” in url ? That must be replaced with the name of collection you try to connect to.